# Encoding of POST requests in JSF 2 on JBoss 7

Tags: character-encoding, richfaces, jboss7.x

I have a problem with values POSTed via h:commandbutton, when I enter special characters (ö, ä. ñ, ..). When the value is submitted via an ajax request (e.g. a change listener on the value, or a4j:commandbutton) everything works find. However when the value is submitted via h:commandbutton, the value received gets garbled.

I've tried to set everything according to the [article written by BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.co.at/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html).

I've set the URI enconding in JBoss' standalone.xml:

```
<property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
<property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
```

Added a filter that sets the character encoding of the request. However this does not change anything, the parameters are messed up there if I read get the param map (either before or after setting the encoding).

Is there anything else I've missed?

I've tried with JBoss 7.1.0 and 7.1.1 and richfaces 4.1.0.

**Edit:**

Even if ExternalContext#getRequestCharacterEncoding() returns UTF-8 in the beans action method (as asked in the comment), it looks like the filter is the problem.
When the form is submitted via h:commandButton, `request.getCharacterEncoding()` returns null at the beginning of the doFilter() method of the UTF filter I added. But `request.parametersParsed` is already true.

When the value is submitted via ajax `request.getCharacterEncoding()` is already UTF-8.

So it looks like the encoding is set differently and some other filter already parses the parameters. The only other filter in the `request.context.filterConfigs` is `org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter`. Plus Picketlink probably already has read the parameters at this point.

**Edit 2:**
As discussed in this [thread in the PL forum](https://community.jboss.org/thread/221662) this seems to be a bug in Picketlink. Also check the related [PL issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLFED-389).

Comment: Yes, I'm using Facelets. Chrome says "Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" for the response header of the page with the form.

Comment: Okay. Is that character encoding filter the very first filter in the chain? It would be too late to set it if some other filter has invoked `getParameter()`. In the meanwhile to debug, what does `ExternalContext#getRequestCharacterEncoding()` say when you print it in the bean's action method?

Comment: It is the only filter in web.xml but I use Picketlink for authentication. This probably reads parameters from the request. However ExternalContext#getRequestCharacterEncoding() returns utf-8 independed of whether the filter is active or not.

Comment: Then everything looks fine. Is your environment also setup to use UTF-8? How exactly are you observing the "garbled characters"? By `System.out.println()`? If so where exactly does this print to? The IDE console? Which IDE?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2 on Ubuntu 12.10. The values look like the encoding is wrong (ö -> Ã¶), I'm checking in debug mode of Eclipse and later in the DB. Also on the next page the wrong values (e.g. Ã¶) is shown. I've edited the question with further information.

Comment: It is maybe a filter order. I do not know Jboss, but it should be possible to set the filter order

Comment: It seems to be caused by Picketlink. I've deactivated it and now everything works. Picketlink uses a Valve and they are apparently called before any filters. It works for ajax requests as the content-type is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8` there. For normal form submits it is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I haven't found a way to set the content type of submitted forms, and picketlink is called before any filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine so far.

This construct will only fail if something else has already accessed (and thus implicitly parsed) the request body *before* your character encoding filter has set the request body character encoding. It's then too late to set the character encoding for parsing of the request body.

Based on the comments, PicketLink seems to be the culprit here. You need to tell it to use UTF-8, or if that's not possible, report a bug/issue report at their development team. This all is at least beyond control of JSF and hence not a JSF related problem.

Comment: Yes Picketlink reads the parameters before, I think the basic problem is that JBoss has hardcoded default encodings and the filter mechanism is unsuited to set the encoding. For reference, I've asked in the [Picketlink forum](https://community.jboss.org/thread/221662) about the issue. As a workaround one could implement a valve, similar to the filter. Thanks for fast the help.